# "missing data from column" error when \copy-ing a csv into postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv, wolfram-mathematica

I'm currently working to make an automated table generator in Mathematica that takes a large csv and splits it in half to avoid the column limit on tables in Postgres.

I've instructed the tables to have every column set to accept null values because of empty columns here and there, yet when I send the \copy command it acts up and complains that some columns are empty near the very end of the 2nd file.

There are other empty columns earlier in the csv that it *doesn't* complain about, and editing the column in question in the csv file doesn't stop (or change) the error either.

The current command reads:

`psql -c \copy table_name  FROM 'file_path\file_name.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' NULL '' CSV HEADER`

The error reads:

Error: missing data for column "column_name"

Context: COPY table_name, line 2: "1,2,3,..."

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question. My suspicion it is not about NULL values but about the number of CSV columns not matching those of the table or vice versa.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't the error be complaining about the very last column instead of one *near* the end?

Comment: Hard to say if you provide edited message and content.  Your best bet is to assume this is an indexing error and verify whether your data columns match up number to the table columns.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get this error if you are copying into a table that has more fields than there are in the csv. What you need to do in this case is specify the CSV fields in the order given in the file's header.

So, if your file has `Field1,Field2,Field3` in the header row then you can copy it into a table that has fields `Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3` and `Field4` like this

```
psql -h mydbhost -c "\copy \"MyTable\"(\"Field1\",\"Field2\",\"Field3\") from 'yourfile.csv' csv header"
```

I've used quoted case-sensitive fields in the example; you may simplify it if that doesn't apply to your use-case.

(thanks to @JGH for nudging me in the right direction)

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of searching, the number of columns in the table *indeed* doesnt match the number in the csv. Which means the list of column names I was supplied (from a csv file which gave a summary of what each column was for) included ones that weren't left blank but *not even used* in the main file.

That I can just blame on negligence on the data supplier and work around.

But I'm confused though why it took other columns to fill them instead of default values or NULL, and then ended up with nothing for the few columns at the end. I though it filled the columns by matching their headers between the table and the csv?

Comment: No, see [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) `Header` "Specifies that the file contains a header line with the names of each column in the file. On output, the first line contains the column names from the table, and on input, the first line is ignored. This option is allowed only when using CSV format."

Comment: I see, it just ignores them. Well, this *should* be as simple as dropping the columns without corresponding columns in the copy file. I'll just have to keep it in mind.

Comment: That and making sure the columns you do include in the CSV match the order of the table columns and the data types of the table columns. For instance, '' will error out on an `integer` field.

Comment: you can also specify the table columns that correspond to the csv "columns" (in the same order):  `\COPY mytable(col3,col1,col999) FROM 'myfile.csv' DELIMITER ...`